# EXCEL How to iterate and add iterator to double entries

Tags: regex, excel

I have an Excel list which does contain a certain number of double entries.
eg.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl5kB.png)

What I want to do is to search each doublette and add an iterator to it. So that the result looks something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQTkM.png)

I've absolutly no idea where to start with this.

Any ideas!?

Comment: Please show an excel picture and attempt of what you're on...it's pretty confusing to figure it out this way...

Comment: no problem. I exchanged the text examples with screenshots from the table.

Comment: sorry, I am new here. As the text example was insufficient and images are also no acceptable way: Is there a way to properly show tables and stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in B2:

```
=IF(A2=A1,A2&"."&COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)-1,A2)
```

And drag down. Let me know if it helps...

Comment: That gives me #NAME?

Comment: Sorry I'm not native english and I've translated badly the function name..please retry ...I've edited..

Comment: Sorry, still saying #NAME?

Comment: this is strange...could produce screenshot?

Comment: Oh I understand. It's because semicolon. Pls test again.

Comment: Thanks again for helping. 
Now it states Err:501 in the first line and Err:508 in all following lines.

Comment: it's some syntax error. please post somewhere an excel, I can't figure it out from here.

Comment: I've uploaded the excel file to my webspace at http://www.winddancer.ws/example.xls

unfortunately it doesn't seem to save the formula you posted. :/

Comment: It seems ok to me. Let's see. If you put:
=COUNTIF(A2:A5,"London")
in B2...does it work?

Comment: unfortunately it also gives Err.501

Comment: I thought it maybe due to Libre Office that the error occurs, so I tried Excel Online.Excel says that the formula contains an error. And doesn't show anything.

Both for the simple examlpe as for your complete formula.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to Black.Jack! You were right all along!

My own stupidity was in my way. ;) I am running a German version of Libre Office, which brings two subtle, but important changes. First conditions etc. must be named German!!! (as a colleague pointed out ;)) 
Secondly the parameters must be seperated by ; and not by , in Libreoffice...

So the working formula for a German Libre Office version is this one:

```
=WENN(A2=A1;A1&"."&ZÄHLENWENN($A$1:A2;A2)-1;A2)
```

again: Thank you very much Black.Jack. Wouldn't have figured it out without your help!!!